# Why would this be getting converted to an int?

Tags: c++, floating-point, trigonometry

I'm setting the X and Y position of an object and the code below is used

```
setX(getX()+(cos(m_fAngleOfShot)));
setY(getY()+(sin(m_fAngleOfShot)));
```

`m_fAngleOfShot` is a float, `setY()` takes a float, and `getY()` returns a float. When this the sprite is modified in the window, it either moves up (delta Y becomes -1), left (delta X becomes -1), diagonal top left (both are -1) or doesn't move at all. It seems that the values returned here are being rounded down and I can't figure out why. Help!

Comment: What is the argument type of `setX()`? I think with the code fragment you posted it is impossible to tell what the problem is.

Comment: The parameter for setX is a float.

Answer (score 1):

`cos()` and `sin()` range between `-1` and `1`.

So, as I'm sure you realise, `setX()` and `setY()` can only ever move up or down 1 pixel.

They also take an argument in radians `-PI` to `PI`.

Is your m_`fAngleOfShot` variable in degrees or radians?

Comment: Ah yes! Of course, they can only move up or down one pixel, that makes sense. When I multiply the cos() or sin() function by 10 it works (albeit much faster). So it would not work at "speeds" less than or equal to one? Am I coding this very inefficiently?